# Is there a way to check ORDS current running processes?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-ords

The following issue happens in multiple browsers, mutiple users both in Dev and Prod Environments.

While working in 4 specific pages, the users are reporting it to freeze at random moments of the day for a few minutes and them summarizing after it. This is not easily replicable and it happen only after a few tries.

Front-end: I've already tested javascript loops, ajax call loops and stackoverflow and none of those seem to be the issue. In Chrome's network tool I'm getting a "Pending" status for X minutes on a returning json from a execute server-side code

Database: the cost for the execution of the processes are all in the single digits. No locks

ORDS: The only information when were able to get was ORDS' log that does something after X minutes. When the page is resposnsive

This all leads me to think something in ORDS is having an issue (or is symptom) or the network.

Has anyone been through a similar issue?

Comment: what are those pages doing? you can debug an apex app AND you can debug in sql developer the pl/sql programs being called by APEX (it's called External Debugging). ORDS is just your plsql gateway for the apex apps calling those sql and plsql programs

Comment: When the issue happens, they are usually bringing a person name and id based on the registration code or based on one of their insurances reference number.
The APEX debug isn't showing any issues and the DBA says there is no problem on the database.

Comment: Still, the APEX Log take as much time for the screen to be responsive to actually log sometihng. The time is the same as the momment the network point the AJAX callback as received.

Comment: what does browser dev tools show on the network panel? and if you want to prove your DBA wrong, try a session trace.

Comment: It show pending reponse for the JSON with the data above.

Comment: and just how is this json payload being created? i don't know what your apex app/page is doing. But you can see what it's doing and then try to attempt the performance problem OUTSIDE of APEX

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248047/discussion-between-paulo-kunzel-and-thatjeffsmith).